# Adding ZXingObjC framework to a project

Tags: xcode, frameworks, addition, zxing

Now that ZXingObjC can be used as a framework I can't figure out for the life of me how to add it to my project.  I followed the instructions on the git page https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC, but when I add `#import <ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC.h>` xcode can't find the file.  The example projects that they provide, however, compile fine.

Answer (score 0):

**The file below does not exist in library header files.**

```
#import <ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC.h>
```

Also set library header file path in **Search Header Path** in **Build Settings**. and import file as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Current answer would be http://cocoapods.org.
Put 
`pod 'ZXingObjC'` into your `podfile`.